# How to launch an AWS cloud formation stack with package dependencies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stack, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to get this repo going: https://github.com/mydatastack/google-analytics-to-s3.

A [link is provided to launch the AWS CloudFormation stack](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=eu-central-1#/stacks/create/review?templateURL=https://public-pipes-ga-s3-cloudformation-stack.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/631216aef6ab2824fc63572d1d3d5e6c.template) but it is no longer working because the S3 bucket containing the template is no longer active.

As a result I'm trying to launch the stack myself via `sam deploy --guided`. This starts to build the stack but fails part way through with the following error:

```
C:\Users\Me\GAS3\cloudformation>sam deploy --guided

Configuring SAM deploy
======================

        Looking for config file [samconfig.toml] :  Found
        Reading default arguments  :  Success

        Setting default arguments for 'sam deploy'
        =========================================
        Stack Name [GA_2_S3]:
        AWS Region [eu-central-1]:
        Parameter Name [pipes]:
        Parameter Stage [local]:
        Parameter AdminEmail [info@project.com]:
        Parameter FallbackEmail [info@project.com]:
        Parameter S3AlarmPeriod [60]:
        #Shows you resources changes to be deployed and require a 'Y' to initiate deploy
        Confirm changes before deploy [Y/n]: y
        #SAM needs permission to be able to create roles to connect to the resources in your template
        Allow SAM CLI IAM role creation [Y/n]: y
        Save arguments to configuration file [Y/n]: y
        SAM configuration file [samconfig.toml]:
        SAM configuration environment [default]:

        Looking for resources needed for deployment: Found!

                Managed S3 bucket: aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-1vcjy21utm1w6
                A different default S3 bucket can be set in samconfig.toml

        Saved arguments to config file
        Running 'sam deploy' for future deployments will use the parameters saved above.
        The above parameters can be changed by modifying samconfig.toml
        Learn more about samconfig.toml syntax at
        https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-config.html


File with same data already exists at GA_2_S3/d5396e95465bde0f60dbd769db9fe763, skipping upload
File with same data already exists at GA_2_S3/df3bbd85d54385405a650fc656f1ac19, skipping upload
File with same data already exists at GA_2_S3/2c01865beec56ebee30ae5b24e6f50e3, skipping upload
File with same data already exists at GA_2_S3/4adb166d233b6e3a1badf491522b0bcc, skipping upload
Error: Unable to upload artifact ./collector-ga.yaml referenced by Location parameter of GoogleAnalyticsCollectorStack resource.
Unable to upload artifact ../functions/lambda-layers/paramiko/ referenced by ContentUri parameter of SFTPLayer resource.
Parameter ContentUri of resource SFTPLayer refers to a file or folder that does not exist C:\Users\Me\GAS3\functions\lambda-layers\paramiko
```

Checking the folder, there is no `./lambda-layers/` folder or `paramiko` package on GitHub. I've tried the downloading `paramiko` package from GitHub and then creating the referenced `/functions/lambda-layers/paramiko/` but this didn't work.

Looking at `./collector-ga.yaml`, this is the section that fails:

```
  SFTPLayer:
    Condition: SFTPUploadActivate
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: paramiko
      Description: paramkio lib for sftp connect
      ContentUri: ../functions/lambda-layers/paramiko/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.7
      LicenseInfo: MIT should be added here 
      RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

The `ContentUri` location given for paramiko isn't there on GitHub, so it must be built some other way since the original repo was meant to launch the working stack from a single press of the button.

My question is: how do I launch this stack with the required paramiko package?

Comment: Appreciate you following up. You definintley added some clarity, I tried using the pre-built layer which fixed the upload error but the stack still isn't deploying successfully. Now it fails on the `GoogleAnalyticsCollectorStack` https://imgur.com/a/SH6c90j . My first question is, how I get the full error traceback to see exactly why does it fail. Secondly, I noticed that the pre-built paramiko layer I added was python 3.8 but the stack GA stack is meant to deploy with 3.7? Would this be the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: how do I launch this stack with the required paramiko package?

You need proper **deployment pipeline**. If you are on AWS, you can deploy lambda functions using [AWS CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-codepipeline.html). Since you have build dependencies, you would need a **build stage** that would actual fetch and build all that is needed for your lambda deployment package or layers.

Or you can use paraminco from some pre-build or public **layers**, such as [this one](https://github.com/jetbridge/paramiko-lambda-layer). This way you are de-coupling your code from your dependencies.