# How to launch AWS cloud formation stack with glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stack, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I'm trying to get this repo going: https://github.com/mydatastack/google-analytics-to-s3.

A [link is provided to launch the AWS CloudFormation stack](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=eu-central-1#/stacks/create/review?templateURL=https://public-pipes-ga-s3-cloudformation-stack.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/631216aef6ab2824fc63572d1d3d5e6c.template), its meant to be one click to launch the stack but it is no longer working because the S3 bucket containing the template is no longer active.

As a result I'm trying to launch the stack myself via `sam deploy --guided  --capabilities CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND CAPABILITY_IAM` since all the resources for the stack are within the repo.  I've added [this lambda layer](https://github.com/jetbridge/paramiko-lambda-layer) for the paramiko package referenced by `collector-ga.yaml` to [fix this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68612100/how-to-launch-an-aws-cloud-formation-stack-with-package-dependencies?noredirect=1#comment121270156_68612100) .

Frustratingly, I'm not quite up and running yet, `GlueConfigurationLambda`, an [AWS lambda function (line 691)](https://github.com/mydatastack/google-analytics-to-s3/blob/master/cloudformation/collector-ga.yaml)   failed to create:

```
Waiting for changeset to be created..

CloudFormation stack changeset
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation                     LogicalResourceId             ResourceType                  Replacement
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Add                         GoogleAnalyticsCollectorSta   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack    N/A
                              ck
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Changeset created successfully. arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:XXXXXX:changeSet/samcli-deploy1628597635/4ee26e-46b5-4131-bdba-1b9fc34f99d6


Previewing CloudFormation changeset before deployment
======================================================
Deploy this changeset? [y/N]: y

2021-08-10 13:14:04 - Waiting for stack create/update to complete

CloudFormation events from changeset
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceStatus                         ResourceType                           LogicalResourceId                      ResourceStatusReason
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS                     AWS::CloudFormation::Stack             GoogleAnalyticsCollectorStack          -
CREATE_IN_PROGRESS                     AWS::CloudFormation::Stack             GoogleAnalyticsCollectorStack          Resource creation Initiated
CREATE_FAILED                          AWS::CloudFormation::Stack             GoogleAnalyticsCollectorStack          Embedded stack
                                                                                                                     arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:
                                                                                                                     XXXXXX:stack/GAN2S3-GoogleAnal
                                                                                                                     yticsCollectorStack-JUATDT3EBD82/e19
                                                                                                                     a4950-ff27-11ea-943e-06072e1f2808
                                                                                                                     was not successfully created: The
                                                                                                                     following resource(s) failed to
                                                                                                                     create: [GlueConfigurationLambda].
```

Full Trace - https://pastebin.pl/view/50b3e402

1. My first question is if there's anywhere to get a more in-depth log of the error?
2. My second question is if anyone knows how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you have a look at the AWS Console CloudFormation application? You should be able to opt to view the Deleted stacks, after which you should be able to select the substack that has failed. In the events list of that deleted stack, you should be able to view a more precise error of what went wrong.

If it's still unclear from that precise error, feel free to edit the question to add the specific error and add a comment to this answer to draw my attention to it.

(Edit)

I've looked through the template file again and noticed the Lambda that's failing is still configured to use Node.js 8, which has been deprecated for some time. You should change it to a newer version, e.g., Node.js 14.
Find the currently supported runtimes here: [Lambda runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html)

Comment: By "CloudFormation application" do you mean this page? https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home. Navigating to the failed stack through the link, I can see `Status reason` as one of the headers of the Events log table. However, the log for the failed substack is the exact same message seen under the `ResourceStatusReason` column in the table above. Feels like im looking in the wrong place so how do I navigate to the cloud formation application?

Comment: You should not look at the stack itself, but at the nested stack that has failed to see the reason. More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html
However, I've looked through the template again, and saw what is wrong. See the edit above.

Comment: Great catch, up and running now thanks to you. I appreciate the help and advice dude!